# R+MongoDB: Dataframe as argument to Find()

Tags: r, mongodb, mongodb-query

- How to pass dataframe cell as an argument to find function:
- I tried this but it throws the below error:

  ```
  Dataset <- mongo$find('{"tagname":agg_df[1,1]}','{"text":1}')
  ```

  Error: Invalid JSON object: {"tagname":agg_df[1,1]}

  ```
   > agg_df[1,1]
   [1] "fruits"

   > typeof(agg_df)  
   [1] "list"        

   > typeof(agg_df[1,1])
   [1] "character"
  ```
- Then, I tried:

  ```
   Dataset <- mongo$find('{"tagname":  "',agg_df[1,1], '"}','{"text":1}')
   > Error: is.numeric(skip) is not TRUE
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
qry_p1 <- paste0('{ "tagname" : "',agg_df[1,1] , '"}')
qry_p2 <- paste0('{"text":1}')
Dataset <- mongo$find(qry_p1,qry_p2)
```